# PyDev for App Engine - re-import External Libs

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I have a project which I created 2 years ago. I need to work on it again, and didn't have it in my Eclipse Workspace so I downloaded it from git and did an import existing projects into workspace. All worked well, except I notice the External Libraries do not contain all the new libraries added to the SDK since I created the project (and there's loads now compared to then). It would be useful if I could select the GAE root dir and let Eclipse automatically pull in all the libs for me, as it does when you create a new project. I don't see a way of doing this other than adding them 1 by 1. Does anyone have any tips?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new project, you get all the new libs. Move your existing (imported) sources to this new project.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but it's a bind. Just wondering if there was an easier way. Thanks anyway

Comment: Seems like this is the only way, so I'll mark your answer as correct ;)